# Convert MKPolygon to UIView

Tags: ios

I have a MKMapView with a Polygon overlay that I need to convert into a UIView.  I have the reference to the MKMapView and the MKPolygon, but I can't seem to find a way to pull the coordinates of the MKPolygon and convert them back into screen coordinates for the UIView.

Comment: How did you draw the MKPolygon onto the UIView?

Comment: Once you have the screen coordinates from the CGPoint it's just a matter of drawing the UIBezierPath into the UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert polygon points to view coordinates (if that is what you need) like this:

[iPhone SDK: Convert MKMapPoint to CGPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129322/iphone-sdk-convert-mkmappoint-to-cgpoint)