# Convert Latitude and longitude to CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, dictionary, mapkit

I have  latitude and longitude which is to be converted to x,y coordinates.I want to subview an image to that point

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive? Are you trying to convert a lat / lng on a MKMapView to x / y screen points (CGPoint)? If so, you can do a `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord= [map convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:map];
    NSLog(@"lat  %f",coord.latitude);
    NSLog(@"long %f",coord.longitude);
    
    [ADD IMAGE HERE VIA ANNOTATION USING LAT LNG]

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}`

Comment: @a1phanumeric I can retrieve the latitude and longitude if I touch on MKMapView.I need to convert that latitude and longitude to CGPoint.

Comment: Hello, why not use something like `CGPoint point = [self.mapView convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:self.mapView];`

Comment: @a1phanumeric:Thanks yaar...it works...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: Convert MKMapPoint to CGPoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129322/iphone-sdk-convert-mkmappoint-to-cgpoint)